# How to use security permissions in combination with a shared user id?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I got a well known security exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: User 1001 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS
```

I added the following line to the android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

But even when I do this I got the same exception.

This has possibly something to do with the shared user id I use:
`android:sharedUserId="android.uid.phone"`, so here my question:

When I use a shared user id (from a system application), can I add my own permissions to the manifest file.

additional information:
I used the same certificate as the system, else I couldn't use the same user id as a system application.

Thanks in advance for your answers and remarks!

Comment: I do not think so..have you asked on the google groups android platform list yet?

Comment: Thank you Fred for your input, I posted the same question to the google groups, I'm now waiting for acceptation by the moderators of the group, so can post a link here...

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/fb00c54e9c60294e?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is old but I just had the same problem in 2019 and only found this un-answered question. I too was tinkering with with android:process & android:sharedUserId to let two apps use the same process and I too got a permissions-error that had previously not occurred before I started tinkering. I always got:

```
Neither user 10003 nor current process has android.permission...
```

What solved it for me was to perform a factory reset.